# Why after I put a context param in web.xml I cannot find my application on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, context-param

I am trying to add

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>common.context</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to my web.xml to allow me retrieve data from company's database
However, after I add it, tomcat cannot find my application, I have no idea why is this happening
Here is my web.xml

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>...</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>...</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>...</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>    
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> -->

<servlet>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>    

<!-- <context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>common.context</param-value>
</context-param> -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

After I added contaxt-param of parentContextKey, the tomcat cannot find my application, it just showing status 404 error, and did not show any messages.

Comment: don't directly try to access your application URL. check Tomcat Logs(catalina.out), whether Tomcat has successfully came up or not.

Comment: Looks like there was an exception during deployment. Read the logs, if you don't understand it very well post the stacktrace of the exception and we'll gladyly help you. Spring and Spring MVC are completely unrelated to this problem.

Comment: If I just put localhost:8080, the server is coming up, just cannot show my application if I use my application URL @Jayesh

Comment: It seems did not show any exception, and there is no any information showing on console @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: delete work folder contents and restart server.